# No type or protocol named 'FlutterPluginRegistrar'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

Flutter issues on ios
In XCode, Some library (SharedPreferences, Apple Sign-In) is showing errors:

`No type or protocol named 'FlutterPluginRegistrar'`

I already tried with: flutter clean, pod update, I cleaned pub-cache and reinstalled all the libraries, the only thing I did not do is delete the pod folder of the ios project (I did it once and then I could not recover the project)

[image: screenshot]

````
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
  Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
  Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
  In file included from
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5
  :
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:7
  :51: error: no type or protocol named 'FlutterPlugin'
  @interface FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin : NSObject <FlutterPlugin>
                                                    ^
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:1
  1:41: error: no type or protocol named 'FlutterPluginRegistrar'
  + (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar> *)registrar {
                                          ^
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:1
  2:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FlutterMethodChannel'
    FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:CHANNEL_NAME
    ^
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:1
  2:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'channel'
    FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:CHANNEL_NAME
                          ^
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:1
  2:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FlutterMethodChannel'
    FlutterMethodChannel *channel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:CHANNEL_NAME
                                     ^
  /Users/zippyttech/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.10/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:1
  4:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'channel'
    [channel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall *call, FlutterResult result) {
     ^
  6 errors generated.
  note: Using new build system
  note: Building targets in parallel
  note: Planning build
  note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.```

Flutter Version: Flutter 1.20.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 216dee60c0 (10 days ago) • 2020-09-01 12:24:47 -0700
Engine • revision d1bc06f032
Tools • Dart 2.9.2

apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0

shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
````

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: yes, first i update flutter, update all libraries in pubspec.yaml, clean again pub-cache,  remove pods, and re-install pods (pod install).

Comment: thanks, I had to make another project and paste all code there.

Comment: i have another problem, about sign in apple and apple store review, but isn't about this issue

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this for some time, and I've found that eleomilagrosa's solution from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57222) works:

```
I found out that the ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework got corrupted the files were all empty or blank.

to fix it,just copy existing ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework from other working Flutter projects you have.
then overwrite the corrupted ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework then build again

Reason:
Flutter.framework got corrupted.

How to identify if your Flutter.framework got corrupted?

open ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h if this file is empty or blank.
```

Answer (score 0):

for the iOS side, you can also try to change the iOS bundle identifier,

[image: 111]

Then it will compile from Zero.